# How can I add a border to a JPanel which is added to a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, border

I have a java swing application which has a nested class called GPanel which extends JPanel.

An instance of GPanel (named graphicsPanel) is added to a JFrame with a GridBagLayout.

Before calling

```
frame.getContentPane().add(graphicsPanel);
```

I call

```
graphicsPanel.setBorder(MyWindow.GRAPHICS_BORDER);
```

Note:

```
private static final Border GRAPHICS_BORDER = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10), BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
```

However the border does not appear.

I would like to have the border appearing around the GPanel.

Below is the full code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class MyWindow {

    //virtual pixels
    private static boolean[][] screenPixels = {

        {true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false},
        {false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true},
        {true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false},
        {false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true},
        {true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false},
        {false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true},
        {true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false},
        {false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true},
        {true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false},
        {false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true},
        {true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false},
        {false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true},
        {true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false},
        {false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true},
        {true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false},
        {false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true},
        {true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false},
        {false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true},
        {true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false},
        {false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true}

    };

    //this is the border i want around my GPanel
    private static final Border GRAPHICS_BORDER = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10), BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));

    //this is the size of the checkerboard inside the GPanel
    private static int dimension = 200;

    private JFrame frame;
    private GPanel graphicsPanel;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MyWindow window = new MyWindow();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public MyWindow() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Alexander Fisher's Game");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        frame.setResizable(false);

        graphicsPanel = new GPanel();
        //this is where i try to set the border
        graphicsPanel.setBorder(MyWindow.GRAPHICS_BORDER);
        graphicsPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(MyWindow.dimension, MyWindow.dimension));
        graphicsPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(MyWindow.dimension, MyWindow.dimension));
        graphicsPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(MyWindow.dimension, MyWindow.dimension));
        frame.getContentPane().add(graphicsPanel);
        frame.pack();

    }

    private class GPanel extends JPanel {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {

            int pixelDimension = MyWindow.dimension / MyWindow.screenPixels.length;

            for(int intRowIndex = 0; intRowIndex < MyWindow.screenPixels.length; intRowIndex++) {
                for(int intColumnIndex = 0; intColumnIndex < MyWindow.screenPixels.length; intColumnIndex++) {
                    if(!MyWindow.screenPixels[intRowIndex][intColumnIndex]) {
                        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                        g.fillRect(intRowIndex * pixelDimension, intColumnIndex * pixelDimension, pixelDimension, pixelDimension);
                    } else if(MyWindow.screenPixels[intRowIndex][intColumnIndex]) {
                        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        g.fillRect(intRowIndex * pixelDimension, intColumnIndex * pixelDimension, pixelDimension, pixelDimension);
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    }

}
```

EDIT(SOLVED):

I added the line:

```
 private static final int BORDER_WIDTH = 11;
```

to the variables for the MyWindow class because part of the problem was that I was painting on top of where the border would have been painted. In addition to this change I updated anywhere the MyWindow.gameDimension variable was used to account for the width of the border.

Next, I changed my method overriding the paint(Graphics g) method to one overriding the paintComponent(Graphics g) method making sure to first call super.paintComponent(Graphics g). @MadProgrammer 's suggestion

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);//added this line

    int pixelDimension = MyWindow.dimension / MyWindow.screenPixels.length;

    for(int intRowIndex = 0; intRowIndex < MyWindow.screenPixels.length; intRowIndex++) {
        for(int intColumnIndex = 0; intColumnIndex < MyWindow.screenPixels.length; intColumnIndex++) {
            if(!MyWindow.screenPixels[intRowIndex][intColumnIndex]) {
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g.fillRect(intRowIndex * pixelDimension + MyWindow.BORDER_WIDTH, intColumnIndex * pixelDimension + MyWindow.BORDER_WIDTH, pixelDimension, pixelDimension);
            } else if(MyWindow.screenPixels[intRowIndex][intColumnIndex]) {
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.fillRect(intRowIndex * pixelDimension + MyWindow.BORDER_WIDTH, intColumnIndex * pixelDimension + MyWindow.BORDER_WIDTH, pixelDimension, pixelDimension);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

EDITED CODE:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class MyWindow {

    //virtual pixels
    private static boolean[][] screenPixels = {

        {true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false},
        {false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true},
        {true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false},
        {false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true},
        {true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false},
        {false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true},
        {true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false},
        {false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true},
        {true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false},
        {false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true},
        {true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false},
        {false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true},
        {true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false},
        {false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true},
        {true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false},
        {false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true},
        {true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false},
        {false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true},
        {true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false},
        {false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true}

    };

    //this is the border i want around my GPanel
    private static final Border GRAPHICS_BORDER = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10), BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));

    //this is the size of the colored square inside the border
    private static int dimension = 200;
    private static final int BORDER_WIDTH = 11;

    private JFrame frame;
    private GPanel graphicsPanel;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MyWindow window = new MyWindow();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public MyWindow() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Alexander Fisher's Game");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        frame.setResizable(false);

        graphicsPanel = new GPanel();
        graphicsPanel.setBorder(MyWindow.GRAPHICS_BORDER);
        graphicsPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(MyWindow.dimension + 2 * MyWindow.BORDER_WIDTH, MyWindow.dimension + 2 * MyWindow.BORDER_WIDTH));
        graphicsPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(MyWindow.dimension + 2 * MyWindow.BORDER_WIDTH, MyWindow.dimension + 2 * MyWindow.BORDER_WIDTH));
        graphicsPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(MyWindow.dimension + 2 * MyWindow.BORDER_WIDTH, MyWindow.dimension + 2 * MyWindow.BORDER_WIDTH));
        frame.add(graphicsPanel);
        frame.pack();

    }

    private class GPanel extends JPanel {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            int pixelDimension = MyWindow.dimension / MyWindow.screenPixels.length;

            for(int intRowIndex = 0; intRowIndex < MyWindow.screenPixels.length; intRowIndex++) {
                for(int intColumnIndex = 0; intColumnIndex < MyWindow.screenPixels.length; intColumnIndex++) {
                    if(!MyWindow.screenPixels[intRowIndex][intColumnIndex]) {
                        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                        g.fillRect(intRowIndex * pixelDimension + MyWindow.BORDER_WIDTH, intColumnIndex * pixelDimension + MyWindow.BORDER_WIDTH, pixelDimension, pixelDimension);
                    } else if(MyWindow.screenPixels[intRowIndex][intColumnIndex]) {
                        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        g.fillRect(intRowIndex * pixelDimension + MyWindow.BORDER_WIDTH, intColumnIndex * pixelDimension + MyWindow.BORDER_WIDTH, pixelDimension, pixelDimension);
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Try `graphicspanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,10,10,10));` You should be using the BorderFactory

Comment: @SteelToe the constant MyWindow.GRAPHICS_BORDER is defined using BorderFactory in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The problem

`public void paint(Graphics g) {` ... this is your key problem

If you take a closer look at [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

> `javax.swing.JComponent` extends this class and further factors the paint method into three separate methods, which are invoked in the following order:
>
> - protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
> - protected void paintBorder(Graphics g)
> - protected void paintChildren(Graphics g)

So, by overriding `paint` and failing to honour the existing the paint chain, you've prevent the border from been painted.

## The solution

As per the recommendations of [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html), you should override `paintComponent` instead (and call `super.paintComponent` before performing any custom painting)